# Image Collection and Compression Conundrum

Tags: javascript, php, image, compression

I have an app that is supposed to collect 360 images from a user on an iPad with a jQuery javascript frontend and a codeigniter php backend. Currently, my app uploads the image to the server the moment it is uploaded to the app, however after user testing I've found that the network connection on the factory floor is too weak to support this so I need to find a new way of doing things. Correct me if I'm wrong but I don't believe the iPad Air 2 can save things as .heic so all of these images should be .jpeg.

A stipulation is that I have to be able to somehow store the images locally, as completing all 360 entries with images takes a long time so I don't want the user to lose progress if they refresh the page or the iPad loses power or anything of the sort.

Another point is that I have to be careful with the RAM of the iPad, as more than once in this process I've managed to crash the iPad with what I assume to have been a memory overload, I don't have any other ideas as to what it could be. Apple says that the iPad Air 2 has 2GB of RAM, and I imagine the amount I have to use is significantly less. The images tend to be 2-3MB, which means that the whole thing, uncompressed, would take up 720-1080MB.

Additionally, I need to be able to display the images on demand (only 1 at a time, thankfully) and be able to swap out that image for another one.

I've been trying to figure out the benefits of using data URIs over zipping the files and frankly I'm a little lost.

This problem sounds simple on paper, but the sheer quantity of images is throwing a wrench into things.

So my question is: what method should I use to capture, store, display, and upload these images in a way that won't crash the iPad and doesn't require immediate upload to a server?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came up with for this ended up being a rather new technology: the [File System Access API's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_Access_API) [Origin Private File System](https://webkit.org/blog/12257/the-file-system-access-api-with-origin-private-file-system/).

For the unaware, this API gets around the limitation that web apps can't access files on the local machine by restricting it to using files and directories that the user consents to or, in the case of the OPFS specifically, a very specific directory that has no access to the rest of the local machine's data.

It only has [limited compatibility with modern browsers at the moment](https://caniuse.com/native-filesystem-api), but I imagine in the next few years we'll see widespread implementation. For iOS, since I need to do this on an iPad, only the OPFS part works, which is great since that's the part I needed.

My method for this ended up being taking a batch of up to 30 images at a time, saving them to the OPFS using a web worker, and then removing those 30 images from RAM. This repeats for the next 11 batches and then prompts the user to move to a location with better connection, tracking the network connectivity with another web worker. Once the app reaches a good connection point they can then begin the upload, uploading all 360 images 1 at a time.

This is far slower of a solution than I would have liked but the alternative was...very, *very* costly.

Anyways, I hope this helps anyone in my situation, although I would rather no one else ever be in my exact situation.